# Advanced Custom Fields - Add Field to Specific Page

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom post type for testimonials. I have each testimonial as a text field titled 'testimonial' using the Advanced Custom Fields. I have a list of pages for services and want to pull a unique testimonial for each respective service page (ie. a testimonial about renovations for the renovation page, a testimonial about their process on the process page).

I selected the Relationship field to select a page for the specific testimonial. After this, I am unsure what to do. I have used the following code but it doesn't seem to work for me...

```
 <?php $fields = get_field('testimonial'); ?>

                    <?php if( $fields ): ?>

            <div class="testimonialbox">                
                        <?php foreach( $fields as $field ): ?>


                            <?php get_field('testimonial', $field->ID); ?>


                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. Either use `get_field` or `the_field`. `get_field` just reads out the field from the db without and screenoutput. like you did in your first line:

```
$fields = get_field('testimonial');
```

`the_field` instead is `get_field` with an implied echo.

```
<?php the_field('testimonial'); ?>
```

so basically the_field would be enough. Aside you have to write a wp_query before and aside i would go with if and while instead of foreach. Like e.g.

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'testimonials'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_field('testimonial'); ?>

        <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        else: ?>
            <p>Error</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

(you would have to refine the query args but basically it would do the trick)

Comment: My custom post type is called 'Testimonials' and the field is 'Testimonial'. Here is my new code.

    <?php
    $testimonials = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonials');
  
    $testimonials = new WP_Query( $testimonials );
    if ( $testimonials->have_posts() ) : while ($testimonials->have_posts() ) : $testimonials->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="testimonialsbox">
    <?php                                                                                               the_field('testimonial'); ?></div>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();else: ?>
    <p>Error</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

Comment: I am getting the Error to show up but my field itself does not show at all. The error also does not show up within my custom div. Not quite sure if I have the proper WP_Query Args in there. This is definitely a step closer.

Comment: I figured it out! I had 'post-type' as the custom post type and not the field! Thank you.

Comment: ah cool you already figured it out. ok i didn't knew your exact post type and field names. those were just placeholders i've used. and one word of advice. i wouldn't use the same variable name for the arguments and the performed query. you enter the arguments array `$testimonials` right into the `wp_query` which is set equal to `$testimonials`again. On one hand confusing on the other hand not the cleanest way of writing things imho. Name one e.g. `$testimonials_args` the other `$testimonials_query`. Easier to read at a later stage.